# Table HTML Code in Inbox Mail from Contact Form

Tags: html, forms, html-table, contacts

I have a code content of the email body contact form as shown below:

```
"Here are the book details:\n Book Title: $title \n Writer: $writer \n Publisher: $publisher \n Sender: $name \n Email: $email"
```

if incoming email inbox result as below:

```
Here are the book details:
Book Title: ...
Writer: ...
Publisher: ...
Sender: ...
Email: ...
```

What code should I add when the incoming email inbox results are as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Book Title</td>
<td class="kanan">........</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Writer</td>
<td class="kanan">.......</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Publisher</td>
<td class="kanan">.......</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Sender</td>
<td class="kanan">....... (email)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5zzznuz/)
, i saw the table is also the same as the /n one. But, still you can try

```
"<table>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Book Title</td>
<td class="kanan">" .$booktitle . "</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="kiri">Writer</td>
<td class="kanan">" . $bookwriter . "</td>
</tr>
</table>"
```